# How to extract a substring on a column in R , delete all after % character

Tags: r

My data is like

```
> head(data$ID)
[1] "1%3ABC" "2%3ABC" "3%3ABC" "8%3ABC" "9%3ABC" "12%3ABC"
```

Now I want cut all `%3ABC` in this column only remain the number before `%`
Thank you very much.

Comment: you could do `sub("%.*", "", data$ID)` OR `sub("%3ABC", "", data$ID)`

Comment: @RonakShah  It is very simple Thank you !

Comment: Do you want your result to be strings `"1", "2", ...` or integers `1, 2, ...`? Also, do you have any preference whether solutions use base R, `stringr`, tidyverse packages like `readr`, or  `data.table`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can just use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
library(readr)
parse_number(v1)
#[1]  1  2  3  8  9 12
```

---

Or using `sub` from `base R` to capture the numbers at the beginning of the string

```
as.integer(sub("^(\\d+).*", "\\1", v1))
#[1]  1  2  3  8  9 12
```

---

Or using `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`

```
as.integer(regmatches(v1, regexpr("^\\d+", v1)))
```

---

Or with `str_remove` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
as.integer(str_remove(v1, "%.*"))
#[1]  1  2  3  8  9 12
```

---

Or from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
as.integer(stri_extract_first_regex(v1, "\\d+"))
#[1]  1  2  3  8  9 12
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("1%3ABC", "2%3ABC", "3%3ABC", "8%3ABC", "9%3ABC", "12%3ABC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this from the `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)
str_split_fixed(data$ID, "%", 2)[,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have `"%3ABC"` in every value we can use `sub` to remove it

```
sub("%3ABC", "", data$ID)
```

OR more generally,

```
sub("%.*", "", data$ID)
```

You can wrap it in `as.integer`/`as.numeric` if you need them as numbers.